# Always Cats in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I know that "semper fidelis" means something like "always faithful". I want to make a little joke by saying something similar to "semper fidelis" but to mean something like "always cats".

Would this be "semper feles"? Is there something else that would work that would sound even more like "semper fidelis" and convey a similar meaning? Or is "semper feles" the best I can do?

Comment: Note that *semper feles* does indeed mean “always cats,” but it could also mean “always a cat” (or “always the cat”). Something that sounds closer (to my ears at least) to *semper fidelis* would be *semper felinus* = “always catlike” (singular).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel That ought to be an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 6):

If you are happy with (decidedly non-classical) zoological Latin, you could say **semper felidae** ("always cats", with "cat" construed in the wider sense, i.e. including tigers etc.).

Comment: What I like about that is that felidae is a neat spoonerism of fideles.